# Why i keep getting 403 forbidden issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i am keep getting 403 forbidden error, i am not able to get my json data at all... here is my html source:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery,ui,easy,easyui,web">
    <meta name="description" content="easyui help you build your web page easily!">
    <title>jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>TreeGrid</h1>
    <script> 
        (function(){
            $.getJSON("data/data.json", function(data){
                    console.log(data); // i am not getting data here
            });
        })();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the path of the url is correct. i am getting the error as :

```
GET http://localhost/~xxxxxx/dataTest/data/data.json 403 (Forbidden)
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try to access http://localhost/~xxxxxx/dataTest/data/data.json directly?

Comment: maybe this link will help [403 forbidden error jquery EasyUI](http://www.rapidsnail.com/developer/topic/2012/94/14/76845/the-easyui-combobox-example-code-from-vs-debugging-the-result-is-not-correct-and-why.aspx)

Comment: sorry, i am getting like this: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /~xxxxx/dataTest/data/data.json on this server.

Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.26 with Suhosin-Patch Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the file in the root folder, and then access it. It will help you exclude the issue with not having access priviledges bellow root folder.

Comment: I tried your approach, and it works! then what is the problem that, i am not able to access from nested folder?